# Text highlighting cuts off on top

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am new to web design. I'm currently working on my school's website, but I encountered a problem. When I highlight a text in .wrap, the highlighting is cut off on the top. Why does this occur and how can I fix it? Thank you for your support.

Test Site: http://whileloop.x10.mx/test/

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: what you have tried??please put it here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlight is cutting off at the top because your `line-height` is set to `70%` on the `.wrap` class. If you keep it at the default and adjust the layout properly (setting the `margin-top` of the `h3` for example if that is what you're after), it will highlight normally.

Answer (score 0):

try change .wrap with this

```
    .wrap {
    color: #313131;
    float: left;
    line-height: 70%;
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    width: 100%;}
```